# Python BLE bluetooth compiler erro

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use two demo ode to scan the bluetooth device.

## 1. simple inquiry example

```
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
print("found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    print("  %s - %s" % (addr, name))
```

## 2. bluetooth low energy scan

```
from bluetooth.ble import DiscoveryService

service = DiscoveryService()
devices = service.discover(2)

for address, name in devices.items():
    print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
```

The 1 works well, but the 2nd code show an error message.

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\bluetooth\ble.py", line 1, in <module>
  from gattlib import *

ImportError: No module named gattlib
```

How to install the gattlib module?
Thanks
Darren

Comment: Are you trying to do this with python2 or python3 ?

Comment: have you tried pip and/or apt-get?